# Angular Material v15 Dialog typography

Tags: angular, sass

I'm struggling with an issue since I've updated Angular Material to version 15, I had to do a migration of components. I migrated dialog component and now I'm struggling with bad typography in my dialogs. I tried to change typography in my material theme scss file. I found this in documentation:

> `mat-dialog-content` uses the font-settings specified by the Material
> Design spec, which includes a rather roomy line-height. If you have an
> information-dense dialog that doesn't look good with these settings,
> you can avoid using `<mat-dialog-content>` and just use a div with
> custom padding, or use custom typography settings that can be applied
> with the `mat.mdc-dialog-typography` mixin.

I tried to use this `mat.mdc-dialog-typography` mixin like this:

```
@include mat.mdc-dialog-typography($custom-typography);
```

But I'm receiving an error that this mixin is not defined. Is anyone facing the same issue? Is there a workaround for this? I don't want to get rid of mat-dialog-content in all my components, I would like to apply typography to dialogs globally.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you include `@use '@angular/material' as mat;`?

Comment: You have to provide the typography to your theme. This is all explained in their guides.

Comment: Yes I did include @use '@angular/material' as mat;

Can you point me to the right documentation? 
As far as I noticed it's only about adding typography globally to the theme, but not for only dialogs. Thanks!

Comment: @whiteBear22, would you mind sharing your customizations to the mdc-dialog typography? I am in the same situation (having lots of information-dense dialogs) and I really dislike the default Angular Material look.

Comment: what about `@include mat.dialog-typography($custom-typography);`. This should be the good one as there is also the legacy one